# Receiving HTTP Error 403: Forbidden CSV download

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-requests

I am trying to access a csv programmatically at the following url: http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductDetailsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate=20180627&reportType=F&productId=425

I have tried this in two ways, one by simply passing the URL to `data_sheet = pd.read_csv(sheet_url)`.  I receive an `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` exception when trying with this method.

```
def get_sheet(self):
        # Accesses CME direct URL (at the moment...will add functionality for ICE later)
        # Gets sheet and puts it in dataframe
        #Returns dataframe sheet

        sheet_url = "http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductDetailsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate="+str(self.date_of_report)+"&reportType="\
        + str(self.report_type)+"&productId=" + str(self.product)

        header = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        }

        data_sheet = pd.read_csv(sheet_url)

        return data_sheet
```

I have also tried pretending to be a browser thinking that perhaps the site was not allowing a direct call to the csv, but then I receive an `Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'requests.models.Response'>` exception

```
def get_sheet(self):
        # Accesses CME direct URL (at the moment...will add functionality for ICE later)
        # Gets sheet and puts it in dataframe
        #Returns dataframe sheet

        sheet_url = "http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductDetailsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate="+str(self.date_of_report)+"&reportType="\
        + str(self.report_type)+"&productId=" + str(self.product)

        header = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        }

        req = requests.get(url = sheet_url, headers = header)

        data_sheet = pd.read_csv(req)

        return data_sheet
```

My end goal is to simply retrieve the CSV at that URL and and return a data frame.  What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** I have done some more fiddling and just printed `req` and i get an output of `Response [200]` which from what I can see in the HTTP docs means the server is receiving my information.  Does anyone know if the issue is that I am directly accessing a URL where a csv is stored that normally, if you click the button the url is associated with, it automatically downloads the file.  In checking my downloads folder I do not see any downloads for the file.  So while the server might be receiving a valid request I may not be handling the url behavior correctly.  Any ideas?

Comment: The second error is actually a pandas error, so your second attempt seems to be downloading the file. can you check the download location whether the cvs file actually appears there? If not, can you print out the contents of rec variable before it fails?

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas  I actually don't have a download location set.  The file actually is coming from this webpage:  http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_quotes_volume_voi.html?optid=190#tradeDate=20180627        I found that URL above by following the link behind the button that's there, which when pressed, automatically downloads the file.  Is there a better way to go about this perhaps that i'm not thinking of?  I am new to python admittedly.

Comment: Hi @StormsEdge. I followed the link and first of all it's an `.xls` file and secondly I opened it and there is an image in the top left corner. So, this probably cannot be parsed properly.

Comment: i posted a sample solution along with some comments below @StormsEdge, although i usually prefer to use file writer to write the cvs to the temp directory. I usually find it more reliable and definitely less ram hungry than in-memory solutions

Answer (score 7):

There are two things wrong with your code:

1. You are passing a response object to pandas,

   `data_sheet = pd.read_csv(sheet_url)`
   when your actual csv data is in `sheet_url.content`
2. pandas cannot read `csv` from `string`, `pd.read_csv` only works with file objects. Thus to read your downloaded content, you need to create a file either using string writer to create a physical file or use `io.StringIO(response.content.decode('utf-8'))`

An example of using io module is:

```
import requests
import io
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/SalesJan2009.csv')

file_object = io.StringIO(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
pd.read_csv(file_object)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use requests with headers to avoid the forbidden 403 error, and then do a skiprows while reading the excel file, to make sure the image inside the file doesn't create problems when importing to python.

```
import pandas as pd    
import requests

hdr = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"} #change the version of the browser accordingly

resp = requests.get('http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductDetailsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate=20180627&reportType=F&productId=425', headers = hdr)

pd.read_excel(resp.content, skiprows = range(0,5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `1.2` of `pandas`, it is possible to tune the used reader by adding options as dictionary keys to the `storage_options` parameter of `read_excel`. So by invoking it with

```py
import pandas as pd


url = ''
storage_options = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
df = pd.read_excel(url, storage_options=storage_options)
```

the library will include the `User-Agent` header to the request so you don't have to set it up externally and before to the invocation of `read_excel`.

Comment: Nice, Oliver! Solved my issue downloading a CSV from Freddie Mac: `df_hpi = pd.read_csv("http://www.freddiemac.com/fmac-resources/research/docs/fmhpi_master_file.csv")` failed with a 403. By adding the `storage_options` above, it fixed the issue.